# Can I change the icon of an error provider?

Tags: vb.net, icons, set, errorprovider

i have this code `Public errorVal As New ErrorProvider`

and this to set the error `errorVal.SetError(Control, "error text")`

and this to clear the error provider `errorVal.SetError(txtNFactura, "")`

but can i change the error icon that appears ???? for a .png or .gif in a folder or resources ?

set a custom icon

this in visual basic . net 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `Icon` property you can use.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.icon(v=vs.90).aspx

A simple google search gives the result https://www.google.co.in/search?q=errorprovider+icon